# -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender.. this function is not called when i select textfield?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitextfield

I m using `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender` this function in my application. this is not called when i select the textfield.
here's the code...

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{  
    if([sender isEqual:txtName])//txtName is the IBOutlet of the UITextField  
    {  
        NSLog(@"Name");  
    }  
    else{  
        NSLog(@"NO_Name");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You asked 10 questions already and accepted no answer so far... please accept answers to your questions so that people will feel more inclined to help you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you set delegate of UITextField's instance to current view controller like this:

`textField.delegate = self;` (self means the instance where callback textFieldDidBeginEditing is overridden)

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to complete 2 simple steps

1 - Implement the delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`

`@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

2 - Set the delegate

`yourTextField.delegate = self`

If you have many text fields in your view, you can set delegate for all of your text fields like this

```
for (id subView in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [subView setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You must include UITextFieldDelegate in .h file

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must include UITextFieldDelegate in your .h file, and also add `YourTextField.delegate = self`